# AJAX call not sending

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create my first AJAX call. All I am trying to do is send a message to my database that will hold a user_id, message, and date.

As of now nothing is even happening when I hit the submit button. Why is this not submitting and I'm not sure if I am creating the ajax call correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

My ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit_announcement").on("click", function () {
        $user = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert_announcements.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "username=" + $user,
            success: function (text) {
                if (text == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to get user info!");
                    $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                    $(".announcement_success").show();
                    $('.announcement_success').html('Payment Status Changed!');
                    $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    var txtArr = text.split('|');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The Form

```
<div class="announcement_success"></div>
<p>Add New Announcement</p>
<form action="" method="POST" id="insert_announcements">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="announcement_message " name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <label for="contactButton">
        <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Add Announcement" id="submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

PHP file insert_announcements.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO announcements (user_id, message, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
         die('Announcement INSERT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->bind_param('isi', $announcement_user_id, $announcement_message)) {
        // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Announcement INSERT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
        die('Announcement INSERT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
        echo "Announcement was added successfully!";
    else
    {
         echo "Announcement Failed!";
    }
```

Comment: I don't use `mysqli` but I think `$stmt2->bind_param('isi', $announcement_user_id, $announcement_message)` should be `$stmt2->bind_param('is', $announcement_user_id, $announcement_message)` because you are only binding 2 values an integer and string.

Comment: @Ralph You are not sending the message and date to the php, in data you have only user and your id of submit is different of the function click in jQuery

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need to send the date, if I have the NOW() setup in the INSERT query?

Answer (score 2):

You have the jquery selector for your button wrong, change it to:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

You are triggering the click for an element with id  `#submit_announcement` which is different from the id of your form submit button. Change  `$("#submit_announcement").on("click", function(){`
to

```
 $("#submit").on("click", function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP you cannot echo between `}` and `else`

```
 }
        echo "Announcement was added successfully!";
    else
```

Comment: Would that echo be above that bracket then?

Comment: How can I change this, so that I echo out a success message?

Comment: just remove `else` and eveything behind

Answer (score 1):

Use one of below event bind method :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){ console.log('reached'); /* code here */ });

    $('#insert_announcements').on('submit',function(){ /* code here */ })


 })
```

One of above approach should work . Your ajax code looks fine . just use one of above event bind wrapper and let the magic happen .

**Update**

check working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/hfddcop0/

Mistakes you were making

1) specifying wrong submit button id . it is submit_announcement instead of #submit

2) Unknown variable defined called usermessage . I have replaced it with string value in fiddle .

payload should be like

```
data : {'message':message,'anothermessgae':another}  , You were mentioning like     data : {'message':message;} which is a syntax error .
```

Comment: Neither one of these worked for me. The network tab is still showing nothing.

Comment: You have document.ready wrap ? and inside wrap this event call right ? Now just after event call , check if console works or not . See edited answer

Comment: check console before network . Any error or consoled message ?

Comment: I don't see anything in the elements or network. No errors, nothing is happening.

Comment: Ok So you have checked your console . element shows your html and network shows requests . there is last option in developer tool called console (In chrome ) elements , network , sources .... audits and then console . You need to check here . If it is not printing anything . then please create a fiddle of your html and js , so we can check .

Comment: I'm now getting an error, but it might be because I was trying to mess with the variables.... here is the JSfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/jhp7ayf4/...there error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` for this line `"message":usermessage;`

Comment: I now get this line for an error ... `"username="$user,`  for `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`...My code also breaks other JS on my page? I'm not sure why.

Comment: it should be "username="+$user . You are making general syntax errors .

Comment: When I do that.... `"username="+$user` I get this error...`ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

Comment: But before that, something is killing my code and my submit button still isn't working. Would this be better to be seen with my full code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yzs286fj/ check this fiddle . You are making syntax error mistakes . paste your code to fiddle and let me see .

Comment: Here you are.... https://jsfiddle.net/s5j4xvnt/... I inserted the source code to weed out the php. The tabs you see on the left, before I posted this thread those worked. If you click on any of the tabs on the left, it should `show` the divs associated with them. For some reason, something in the announcements div....the one I am working on, is breaking that.

Comment: Ok, great. It is now sending to my php file, but nothing is being inserted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86799/discussion-between-ralph-and-creator).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not creating the function when the submit button is clicked. The button id is `submit`

So try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#submit").on("click", function(){
            $user = this.value;
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: "username="+$user, 
                success: function(text){ 
                    if(text == "Error!"){ 
                        alert("Unable to get user info!"); 
                        $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                        $(".announcement_success").show();
                        $('.announcement_success').html('Payment Status Changed!');
                        $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                        alert(data);
                    } else { 
                        var txtArr = text.split('|');
                    } 
                }, 
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                    alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown); 
                } 
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending user_id, message, and date to server to get the response.
first get inputted values and then send.Like below:

```
var announcement_message = $("#announcement_message).val();
```

and instead of type,it should be method.Type in ajax is to define data type.
In html, remove method="post",define method only once.

Comment: Well the user_id, is the users current id. The date is a NOW() field. So that var pulls from the id? How do you grab it in my php file?

Comment: So like this? `} else { 
        var announcement_message = $("#announcement_message").val();
       } `

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#submit").on("click", function(){

var usermessage = $("#announcement_message).val();
var username = "ralph"; // let say you get the username value;
var date_now = Date.now();

$.ajax({
url:"insert_announcements.php",
method:"POST",
data:{
    "user_id":username,
    "message":usermessage,
    "date":date_now

}
success:function(data){
  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
},
error:function(){
console.log("error");//otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
}

});


});
```